# Multinomial coefficient notation?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How does one evaluate this

$$\binom{5}{2, 2, 1}$$

would it be something like $\dfrac{5!}{2! \cdot 2! \cdot 1!}$ or does it evaluate differently then the usual 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
can someone explain?

Comment: Your guess is right. The usual binomial coefficient can be written as $\left({n \atop {k, {n-k}}}\right)$. One can drop one of the numbers in the bottom list and infer it from the fact that sum of numbers on the bottom should be the number on top. The two notations are then compatible.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).

Answer (score 4):

You are right. An expression like $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3.....,k_l}$ is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{n!}{k_1!.k_2!.....k_l!}$

You can also write $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}$ as $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k,n-k}$ but as this is used so often so the first one is preferred.

If you go to multinomial case then the coefficients will be somewhat like this i.e

$\displaystyle \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_i\right)^n=\sum_{\sum_{i=1}^m k_i=n}^{}\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3.....,k_m}\prod_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_i^{k_i}$

Regarding understanding the notation: $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3.....,k_l}$ is Chosing $k_1$ objects from a collection of $n$ objects follwed by choosing $k_2$ objects from the rest $(n-k_1) $ objects and so on. Lastly $k_l $ objects from the remainint $(n-\sum_{i=1}^{l-1}k_i)$ objects.

Comment: how does one understand that notation though, for example 5 choose 2 means there is a set of 5 objects you must choose 2 objects, 5 choose 2 means how many ways you could select 2 objects out of the 5. what about the (5 choose 2,2,1), how can i understand this notaion

Comment: @notamathwiz $\displaystyle{n\choose k_1,\cdots,k_r}$ counts the number of ways to put $n$ items into $r$ labelled bags, the first one containing $k_1$ elements, the next containing $k_2$, and so forth.

Comment: @anon, well, the number of ways to put $k_1$ items in the 1st bag, $k_2$ in the 2nd, and so on.

Comment: @notamathwiz, the multinomial coefficient represents the ways you can arrange $n$ objects, of which $k_1$ are of type 1, $k_2$ are of type 2, ... In this sense, the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ is number of ways in which you can arrange $k$ "included" marks along $n$ candidates (and $n - k$ "excluded" marks, obviously).

Comment: Now is it okay @notamathwiz